# Calculate the distance to a red point with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

i'm newbie with opencv. Just managed to install and set it up to Visual 2013. I tested it with a sample of live stream for my laptop's camera and it works. Now i want to calculate the distance with the webcam to a red laser spot that will be in the middle of the screen(live_stream). Tell me from where can i start? I know that i must find the R(red) pixel from the middle of the screen but i dont know how to do that and what functions can i use. Some help, please?
The live stream from webcam that works is shown below:

```
   #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
   #include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {

 //Data Structure to store cam.
 CvCapture* cap=cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
 //Image variable to store frame
 IplImage* frame;
 //Window to show livefeed
 cvNamedWindow("Imagine Live",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while(1)
{
//Load the next frame
frame=cvQueryFrame(cap);
//If frame is not loaded break from the loop
if(!frame)
    printf("\nno");;
//Show the present frame
cvShowImage("Imagine Live",frame);
//Escape Sequence
char c=cvWaitKey(33);
//If the key pressed by user is Esc(ASCII is 27) then break out of the loop
if(c==27)
   break;
}
//CleanUp
cvReleaseCapture(&cap);
cvDestroyAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated C Api (IplImage, cvShowImage etc) as you will run into so many problems.

Comment: Then what should i use?

Comment: Preferably opencv 3.0 but its in beta so use 2.4.10 and use the C++ Api (CV::mat, CV::imshow) etc

Comment: Is the red poing going to move?

Comment: Opencv 3.0.0 is not a beta anymore

Comment: The red dot won't move

Answer (score 0):

Your red dot is most likely going to show up as total white in the camera stream, so I would suggest

1. Convert to grayscale using [`cvtColor()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor).
2. Threshold using [`threshold()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold), for parameters use something like thresh=253, maxval=255 and mode THRESH_BINARY. That should give you an image that is all black with a small white dot where your laser is.
3. Then you can use [`findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) to locate your dot in the image. Get the [`boundingRect()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=bounding%20rect#boundingrect) of a contour and then you can calculate its center to get the precise coordinates of your dot.

Also as has been already mentioned, do not use the deprecated C API, use the C++ API instead.

Comment: Thank You! I'l try what you've told me and i'l come back with more questions.